# Examples that the conclusion of Arzela-Ascoli does not follow when equicontinuity or uniform boundedness is dropped?

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-convergence, uniform-continuity

I am looking for a sequence of functions that satisfies these properties:

**$1$.** Let $I=[0,1]$. $f_n\in C(I)$ and are continuously differentiable

**$2$.** $f_n(0)=0$ for every $n$

**$3$.** $|f_n'(x)|\le \dfrac{1}{1-x}$ for every $x\in (0,1)$

**$4$.** The sequence $(f_n)$ has no uniformly convergent subsequence on $I$

I would like for $f_n$ to be either not equicontinuous (when considering the sequence as a family of functions), or for them to not be uniformly bounded. I can come up with a few examples that work barring condition $(2)$, but none with all of them. Any ideas?

Comment: What is an example at your hand that fits (2)? Please also show it in your question.

Comment: You are not looking for a counterexample to Arzela-Ascoli, for there are none: the theorem is true. You should try to find a more precise title!

Comment: Well, no: there is *no* failure of the theorem: that is precisely why the theorem is true!. What you want is something like «Failure of the conclusion of Arela-Ascoli when its hypothesis does not hold» or, much better, «An example showing the necessity of the hypothesis of the Arzela-Ascoli theorem».

Comment: (Please, do not delete questions for which there are already perfectly good answers!)

Answer (score 2):

Let $f_n(x)$ be the polynomial
$$f_n(x)=\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{x^k}{k}.$$

It is clear that **1)** and **2)** are satisfied. **3)** holds because $f_n'(x)$ is a partial sum of the infinite series for $1/(1-x)$.

To prove **4)**, suppose for contradiction that a subsequence of $\{f_n\}$ converged uniformly to some function $g$. Then $g$ is a continuous function which vanishes on $[0,1)$, so $g(1)=0$. On the other hand, $f_n(1)\to\infty$ (because the harmonic series diverges). This contradicts subsequential uniform convergence, so property **4)** holds.

Comment: Thanks, I was lazy and included only the highest degree monomial in the Taylor polynomial for $-\ln(1-x)$. I fixed it by including the entire Taylor poylnomial. Good catch!